# `--trigger-resource' description error for cloud firestore trigger

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying an example of Cloud Functions trigger based on Cloud Firestore. While deploying the function using `gcloud`, I am getting this error:

```
gcloud functions deploy hello_firestore --runtime python32  
    --trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.update  
    --trigger-resource projects/patch-us/databases/ (default) 
    /documents/books/{booksid}
```

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Can someone point out whats wrong with the command line?

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis around your database name, like `projects/patch-us/databases/default/documents/books/{booksid}`

Answer (score 1):

It was a very stupid mistake..

`gcloud functions deploy hello_firestore --runtime python32  --trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.update  --trigger-resource "projects/patch-us/databases/(default)/documents/books/{booksid}"`

The path needs to be within inverted commas.